# How to stop threads when one of them finds a prime number

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, synchronization

When a prime number is found, I have to stop it. When I use *synchronized* before  the `while`, only one thread process will occur. However, multiple thread operations should occur, but all should stop when prime is found.

The initial value of `i` in the control part has been changed.

What I want to do is to find prime numbers using lock and synchronized.

```
public abstract class NumberGenerator {

    private boolean isStop;

    public abstract int generateNumber();

    public void stop() {
        this.isStop = true;
    }

    public boolean isStopped() {
        return isStop;
    }

}

public class IntegerNumberGenerator extends NumberGenerator {

    private Random random;
    int randomAtama;

    public IntegerNumberGenerator() {
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public int generateNumber() {
        return random.nextInt(100) + 1;
    }
}

public class PrimeNumberChecker implements Runnable {

    private NumberGenerator generator;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public Condition continueLock = lock.newCondition();

    public PrimeNumberChecker(NumberGenerator generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!generator.isStopped()) {

            int number = generator.generateNumber();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " generated " + number);
            if (check(number)) {
                System.out.println(number + " is prime !");
                generator.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean check(int number) {

        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if ((number % i) == 0) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        NumberGenerator numberGenerator = new IntegerNumberGenerator();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new PrimeNumberChecker(numberGenerator));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimized the check method to:

```
public static boolean check(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
        if ((number % i) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

as soon as you know that the number is not a prime you can just return earlier.

> When I find a prime number, I have to stop it. If I use it before
> synchronized while, only one thread process will occur. Multiple
> thread operations should occur, but should stop when prime is found.

You can achieve this by adding first *volatile* to the `isStop` flag:

```
 private volatile boolean isStop = false;
```

then checking for `generator.isStopped()` (also) in the method that finds out if a number is prime:

```
public boolean check(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
        if (generator.isStopped() || number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Finally, you need to synchronize while reading the value of `check` method because it might happen that multiple threads find the prime number at the same time. So adapt your code to:

```
    boolean result = check(number); // All threads to work in parallel
    synchronized (generator) {
        if (result && !generator.isStopped()) {
            System.out.println(number + " is prime !");
            generator.stop();
        }
    }
```

*Volatile* here is not enough because multiple threads might managed to enter inside the block of code within the

```
if(result && !generator.isStopped())
```

before one of them is able to actually call `generator.stop()`;. Making the variable `isStop` `AtomicBoolean` *alone* would also not help, because of the exact same reason.

The point is the statements `!generator.isStopped()` and `generator.stop();` have  to be performed within the same critical region, either using synchronized or performing the two operations atomically in the same go. Therefore, for the `AtomicBoolean` to work you would have to do the following:

```
public abstract class NumberGenerator {

    private final AtomicBoolean isStop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public abstract int generateNumber();

    public void stop() {
        this.isStop.set(true);
    }

    public boolean isStopped() {
        return isStop.get();
    }

    public boolean getAndSet(){
        return isStop.getAndSet(true);
    }
}
```

and

```
 if (check(number) && !generator.getAndSet()) {
       System.out.println(number + " is prime !");
   }
```

Because the `getAndSet` is done atomically, you do not run the risk of having multiple threads printing out their primes.

> What I want to do is to find prime numbers using lock and
> synchronized.

If you mean using only one or the other (since you do not need to use both) then you can do the following:

```
    boolean result = check(number);
    synchronized (generator) {
        if (result && !generator.isStopped()) {
            System.out.println(number + " is prime !");
            generator.stop();
        }
    }
```

this would work even without the *volatile*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the logic of "when it should stop" in the abstract class, the Thread itself should be aware of it. So I would add an AtomicBoolean as a flag inside of the Runnable class and a stop() method to deal with it. Then the run method would be looking for the AtomicBoolean to stop whenever this boolean changes.

Something like this:

```
public class PrimeNumberChecker implements Runnable {
    //Flag to control the running
    private final AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private NumberGenerator generator;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    public Condition continueLock = lock.newCondition();
    
    public PrimeNumberChecker(NumberGenerator generator) {
        this.generator = generator;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {     
       isRunning.set(true);
       while (isRunning.get()) {        
            int number = generator.generateNumber();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " generated " + number);
            if (check(number)) {
                System.out.println(number + " is prime !");
                generator.stop();
            }
    
        }
    
    }       
    
    // So you can stop it from the outside
    public void stop() {
        isRunning.set(false);
    }

    public static boolean check(int number) {
    
        boolean result = true;
        for (int i = 0; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if ((number % 2) == 0) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this process. It gave the same result again. When it was the prime number, it did not stop.

Comment: Hi Fransisco, the problem with your current solution is that the flag isRunning is private to each thread.

Comment: Yes @dreamcrash, the variable is private but there is a public method "stop" to deal with it.

Comment: The method is public but the each threads has its own private variable, they are not sharing the same memory reference

Comment: You are right, I thought that one per thread could be enought but maybe he wants to stop all the threads, not each one. Good catch!

Comment: @FranciscoTena np glad to help